# How to compare null in rails active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, null

How can I match null in rails active record.

```
User.where(['id = ? and active = ? and activation_code = ?', params[:id], 0, NULL]).first
```

or

```
 User.where(['id = ? and active = ? and activation_code = ?', params[:id], 0, nil]).first
```

Both are not working.

Comment: What is this "where" method? Never seen it before.

Comment: Also, what error are you getting?

Comment: @tybro0103 Mysql, and its rails 3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
User.where(['id = ? and active = ? and activation_code IS NULL', params[:id], 0]).first
```

Answer (score 25):

The trick is using a hash, in which case ActiveRecord will correctly generate SQL for nil values, using "IS NULL".

```
User.where({:id => params[:id], :active => 0, :activation_code => nil})
```

Comment: I really love https://github.com/ernie/squeel for that. You can say `User.where{(id == my{params[:id]}) & (active == 0) & (activation_code != nil)}`

Comment: Check out http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/not-equal-support-for-active-record-queries-rails-4-countdown-to-2013 for Rails 4's `not` method

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 4 you can do this:

```
User.where(id: params[:id], active: 0).where.not(activation_code: nil)
```